# Getting month from boost date object

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

I have a boost::date object. When I call month() interface on the object it returns me the month the object is holding but in terms of a string. Is there a way I can get the number associated with the month? i.e

```
date mySampleDate = date_from_tm(tm_myDate) ;
cout<<mySampleDate.month() ; //Gives the output as May/Jun/Jul etc. I need 5/6/7 etc.
```

I need to get this without recoverting the boost object into tm structure. This would result in too many converstions and a possible performance hit for me.

Comment: Seems like a bug in Boost, to me. I saw the same behavior in 1.66, but boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/date_time/… says: Get the month part of the date. date d(2002,Jan,10); d.month(); // --> 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cout<<mySampleDate.month().as_number();` is exactly what you want!

Comment: how is this implemented in boost? Is .month() returning some class that has method as_number()?

Comment: @BehroozKarjoo Internally `boost::date` is a template class, one of its template parameter, `calendar` defines the policies for converting the the year-month-day. `month()` returns `calendar::month_type`.